VBA Listbox events trigger multiple times
EDIT: After more fiddling around I discovered that the problem may not have to do with the listbox at all. The named cell I used as Control Source has data validation with a drop-down list. I just tried selecting from one of those lists, and the same thing happens: the cell clears immediately. I'm trying to figure out why.
ORIGINAL:
I have a listbox on a userform. The ControlSource is connected to a named cell on a worksheet.
When I select an item from the list, it won't stay selected. The selection, and the cell its linked to by ControlSource, are immediately deselected.
I did some testing in the listbox events. (In the entire project, none of the other events have code except for Userform_Initialize and btnClose_Click.)
Private Sub lsttxntype_Change()
    Debug.Print "Change event triggered"
End Sub

Private Sub lsttxntype_Click()
    Debug.Print "click event triggered"
End Sub

Private Sub lsttxntype_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "BeforeUpdate triggered"
End Sub

Private Sub lsttxntype_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "AfterUpdate triggered"
End Sub

Most of the events trigger twice:
Change event triggered
click event triggered
BeforeUpdate triggered
AfterUpdate triggered
Change event triggered
BeforeUpdate triggered
AfterUpdate triggered

However, when I slow the code down with breakpoints or Stop commands, it changes. Here I put a breakpoint at the End Sub of Change, clicked the listbox, and let it continue after it stopped:
Change event triggered
click event triggered
Change event triggered
click event triggered

Here I put the breakpoint at the start of AfterUpdate:
Change event triggered
click event triggered
BeforeUpdate triggered
AfterUpdate triggered

(I think the listbox selection is deselected in the AfterUpdate event.)
Since all I have to do is pause the execution to get a different result, I think there must be some kind of background timing issue.
If I leave ControlSource blank, then none of this happens. But it also means I need to use code to update the cell from the listbox and vice versa. (I'll do that if I have to, but either way it would be good to resolve this question)

I have a listbox on a userform. The selection, and the linked cell .. - There isn't LinkedCell property if it is a listbox on a userform. Do you use ActiveX ListBox on worksheet?

By "linked cell" I didn't mean "LinkedCell". I meant "ControlSource". I'll edit above.

Is there any code related to the listbox in the Userform_Initialize event? I can't reproduce it on M365.

Why would you use a list box for a single cell? Use a text box instead. The ControlSource property of a list box is used e.g. to specify the header cell (Field) of an Excel table (ListObject), which would then populate the column values (incl. headers) in the list box. Then there is the RowSource property which you can utilize similarly for 'table' data that is not in an Excel table.

@VBasic2008 I want the user to be able to choose from a list either on the userform or in a single cell on the worksheet itself. The list of choices is in a named range, which I enter in both the RowSource of the listbox and the Data Validation list of the single cell. The plan was to enter the address (or name) of that single cell as the ControlSource of the listbox.
